# Android get a cursor only with contacts that have an email listed

Tags: android, contacts

Friends I want Contacts which have email and also sort in ascending order..

any one know how to get this list and sort..

Please  help me and thanks in advance.

I am using this code.

```
        MatrixCursor matCur = new MatrixCursor(new String[] { Contacts._ID,
                Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME, "photo_id", "starred" });
        Cursor cEmail = WP7Main.this.managedQuery(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
        cEmail.moveToFirst();
        if (cEmail.moveToFirst()) 
        {
            // String name =
            // cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(People.NAME));

            String contactId = cEmail.getString(cEmail.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));

            Cursor emails = WP7Main.this.getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI,
            null,ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTACT_ID+ " = " + contactId, null, null);

            String emailAddress = "";
            while (emails.moveToNext()) 
            {
                // This would allow you get several email addresses

                if (emails.getString(emails.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA)) != null)
                {
                    String[] columnValues = {
                            cEmail.getString(cEmail
                                    .getColumnIndex("_id")),
                                    cEmail.getString(cEmail
                                    .getColumnIndex("display_name")),
                                    cEmail.getString(cEmail
                                    .getColumnIndex("photo_id")),
                                    cEmail.getString(cEmail
                                    .getColumnIndex("starred")) };
                    matCur.addRow(columnValues);

                }

            }
            emails.close();
        }
```

Comment: what problem are you facing? like fetching the records or in sorting them as you didnt even mentioned in this post also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5205999/android-get-a-cursor-only-with-contacts-that-have-an-email-listed-android-2-0

Comment: that question was not asked by me.

Comment: I know but havenbt you mentioned there also what exactly your problem is

Comment: my problems are both , get email contact and also sort them

Comment: ok post your code what are you trying?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
/**
 * @return A managed cursor of email contacts for the given activity.
 */
public static Cursor buildFilteredEmailCursor(Activity activity) {
    final String my_sort_order = ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " COLLATE LOCALIZED ASC";
    String my_selection = ContactsContract.Contacts.IN_VISIBLE_GROUP + " = '1'";
    String[] eproj = new String[]{
        ContactsContract.Contacts._ID,
        ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME,
        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA};
    Uri uri = android.provider.ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI;
    return activity.managedQuery(uri, eproj, my_selection, null, my_sort_order);
}
```

Comment: BEWARE: I upvoted this hours ago, but have come back to get back that vote. You have to realize that with this answer you are querying the CommonDataKinds.Email table. Even though you say to select ContactsContract.Contacts._ID, that simply trasnlates to the column "_id", which in the Email table case, means that it will be associated to the email AND NOT THE CONTACT ID. Again, beware of this possible answer because it can lead to incongruency unless you know what you are doing.

Answer (score 1):

Use this query :

```
Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(Data.CONTENT_URI,
        new String[]{Data.CONTACT_ID, Data.DISPLAY_NAME, Email.ADDRESS},
        Data.MIMETYPE + "=?", new String[] {Email.CONTENT_TYPE}, Data.DISPLAY_NAME /* use Email.ADDRESS if you want to sort it using that*/);
```

Comment: when i m use this then this error is coming java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0

Comment: Do you have any contacts in your database ?

Comment: Its working for me. Can you please add the whole code that you are using ?

Comment: I'm testing this on Froyo (2.2)

Comment: Use Data.DATA1 in place of Email.ADDRESS

Comment: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0