# Android - Listing all contacts with email

Tags: android, android-contacts

in this question : [Android get a cursor only with contacts that have an email listed >android 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5205999/android-get-a-cursor-only-with-contacts-that-have-an-email-listed-android-2-0) DArkO said that has resolved problem of listing only contacts with email. But I still can't figure out what is that filter string he used. I saw someone was asking him in comment, but without any response.

Or maybe someone else know easy way to get contacts with email?

Answer (score 0):

You can query Data table set where clause to mimetype = Email.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE and get the raw_contact_id. Then using this raw_contact_id you can get any info about this contact.